# NextJS public environment variables are not recognized in my elastic beanstalk

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Here is my problem :
I have a NextJS 14 application with app router, that I would like to deploy on Elastic Beanstalk.

I have some variables  `NEXT_...` and variables `NEXT_PUBLIC_...`.

I write them in my Elastic Beanstalk configuration. But the problem is that I have a client page that should use my `NEXT_PUBLIC_...` variables to create a redirect URL. But when I hover my button with the redirect URL, I have some `undefined` instead of my public variables.

My variables are well written in my application and my configuration, no spelling problems.

Can someone explain me how can I send my `NEXT_PUBLIC_...` variables to my client page ? Do I necessarily need to write a `.env` file for my public variables ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.